# Pros and cons of displaying 2 CTA for the same purpose?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing

I am building a comment section and I am trying to display clear call to actions to get the user to participate in the current debate.

I put into perspective statistics about the comment section and the two best contributions.

Here is what it looks like on desktop and on phones

[image]

[image]

I thought two buttons would do the trick to get the user to the comment section but my users tests weren't as successful as expected.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am building a comment section and I am trying to display **clear call to actions** to get the user to participate in the current debate.

Your current design contradicts what you say you're looking for: the ***clear call to actions*** is visually subordinated to all the info content. In fact, all of the design contrasts are in favor of the content, not the action button: size, shape, color, proportion, spacing...

[image]

Although if this information is necessary and should occupy a larger space, some visual organization is necessary when designing. It can help to work at the schematic level to prioritize and relocate elements.

[image]

Without knowing the design base, I think organizing all the information within a single section and defining the action to this whole set can help:

[image]

For the responsive version it's exactly the same layout arranged vertically. To adjust the space and give greater importance to the container and its button, the content can be inside a slider.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks ! Do you have any leads for the responsive version ?

Comment: Answer updated with a responsive layout.

Comment: Great really helpful !